# SWRevealController Switching Views

Tags: ios

I've setup a SWRevealController in my project and has followed a view tutorials. The problem is that I cannot figure out how to switch to another view when an Item in my tableview in the RevealControllerView page is clicked.

I've tried to use this:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newFrontController];

[revealController pushFrontViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

However, when I use this code, I get an empty navigation controller with a black view page. The code seems to run in the profileViewController, however, this view docent load.

Here's my storyboard. I want them to click an item in my table and then go to the ProfileViewController View.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect the Menucontroller with your next Navigation Controller/View controller by using the "SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController" Segue. 
   => For each ViewController you need an own segue!
2. Perform the right segue

   ```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

   switch(indexPath.row){
   case 0:
       performSegueWithIdentifier("goto_test1", sender: self)
       break
   case 1:
       performSegueWithIdentifier("goto_test2", sender: self)
       break
   case 2:
       performSegueWithIdentifier("goto_test3", sender: self)
       break
   default:
       break
   }   }
   ```